# how can I show launchurl inside of modal bottom sheet?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to give card payment screen inside of modal bottom sheet.But whatever I do ,application opens external page for card payment screen.How can I do it?
[image: I want to do the same thing as it shown in the picture.It is from another app]

For better understanding I share my code with you.Help me please...

```
await showModalBottomSheet(
                              elevation: 10,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                              isScrollControlled: true,
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) {
                                return Container(
                                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                          topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                                          topRight: Radius.circular(30))),
                                  height:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                            top: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .height *
                                                0.03,
                                            left: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .width *
                                                0.05),
                                        child: Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Container(
                                                height: 40,
                                                width: 40,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    color: AppColors
                                                        .drawerTextListTileColor,
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.circular(
                                                            10)),
                                                child: IconButton(
                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                      Navigator.of(context)
                                                          .pop();
                                                    },
                                                    icon: const Icon(
                                                      Icons.close,
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                    ))),
                                            const Spacer(),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      FutureBuilder(
                                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                          if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                              ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                            return Column(
                                              children: const [
                                                Spacer(),
                                                Center(
                                                  child:
                                                      CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                                ),
                                                Spacer()
                                              ],
                                            );
                                          }
                                          return Text('aa');
                                        },
                                        future: launchUrl(
                                            Uri.parse(
                                                resultParsed.topUpWallet.url),
                                            mode: LaunchMode.platformDefault),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            );
```

I tried some ways but still unable to do it.Card payment webview should be seen only from the inside of modal bottom sheet.I do not want it open external webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use webview_flutter instead of url_launcher. This code worked for me. You can check the package page for more details.

[webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

```
showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return WebViewWidget(
              gestureRecognizers: gestureRecognizers,
              controller: WebViewController()
                ..loadRequest(
                  Uri.parse('https://google.com'),
                ),
            );
          },
        );
```

The gestureRecognizers here make the page scrollable.

You can use this code for gestureRecognizers.

I hope it works for you.

```
final Set<Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>> gestureRecognizers = {Factory(() => EagerGestureRecognizer())};
```

[image]